# How to Live Stream Video from a Wireless Camera?

Tags: html, browser, camera, video-streaming, live-streaming

How do I live-stream video from a camera to a web browser, when connected via wifi?

The camera will be connected to a device (NVIDIA module) with a USB dongle or PCIe card. If the user's laptop is connected to the device's wifi, how can the user see the live-stream on their web browser?

Using HTML or MJPGStreamer are my thoughts so far.

Comment: What is the format supported by camera? Is it RTSP? You need to provide additional details in order for someone to give you correct answer.

Comment: 'RTSP' is not format it is a Streaming protocol,